# Package algorithm2e on Ubuntu

Tags: packages, ubuntu, algorithm2e

I am having some trouble getting a LaTeX document to compile. I would like to use the package `algorithm2e`. I am working on a machine running Ubuntu. I tried using Texmaker and Gummi (LaTeX editors) and got same errors on both:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `algorithm2e.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

Also I have texlive distribution. When I did this on my windows machine (with MiKTeX) it worked like a charm. Suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: algorithm2e was the first one I heard of (recommended by professor)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Superior how, exactly? Just curious.

Comment: @Dervin (1) Markup: I don’t particularly like the curly braces,; I hate the `\;`, it renders the markup unreadable. Also, why is there `\lIf` etc? The many abbreviations in macro names, too, make readability worse. And all these comments to control indent, newlines, etc. don’t have a place – it feels way more “low-level” than `algorithmicx`. (2) Typesetting: I never liked the Cormen pseudocode typesetting, which this package is emulating. The lines connecting block delimiters are nice, but noisy. (3) Configurability: Look at my linked example to see how extensively I configure my pseudocode.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487407/package-algorithm2e-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You probably have not installed [the full TeX Live](http://packages.ubuntu.com/texlive-full) but only [a decent selection of it](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/texlive). To get the package you are after you can either

- install the full distribution, or
- just install the package [texlive-science](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/texlive-science) which contains `algorithm2e` (the same package also contains `algorithmicx`).

To install the latter you can issue the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-science
```

Comment: Do you know how to fix this in Fedora?
The corresponding ```sudo dnf install texlive-science``` didn't work. I also don't want to install the full TeX Live.